# Document structure returned by include_docs couchbase

Tags: ember-data, couchbase, couchbase-lite, couchbase-sync-gateway

I have an [Ember app](https://github.com/wholcomb/habit_tracker) that is interfacing with Couchbase Lite via [ember-couchdb-kit](https://github.com/roundscope/ember-couchdb-kit).

I would like to run it on a desktop. I have used CouchDB successfully in the past, but want to migrate to Couchbase Server to better control data access.

Ember-couch-kit relies on an `all` view to return elements of a particular type. For example, my app has habits, the url used for loading those is:

```
/db/_design/habit/_view/all?include_docs=true&key="habit"
```

The map function looks like:

```
function( doc ) { emit( doc.type, null ) }
```

As best I can tell, CouchDB and Couchbase Lite return a result of the form:

```
{
  "total_rows":19,
  "offset":0,
  "rows":[
    {
      "id":"ce236fe89785d8190abc37e01c001087",
      "key":"habit",
      "value":null,
      "doc":{
        "_id":"ce236fe89785d8190abc37e01c001087",
        "_rev":"5-1a6274e9f8020e03277f764fd3fb6bba",
        "type":"habit",
        "name":"Test",
        "color":"#000000",
        "events":["ce236fe89785d8190abc37e01c00267d",…]
      }
    },
    ⋮
```

Couchbase Server, on the other hand, returns a document of the form:

```
{
  "total_rows":1541,
  "rows":[
    {
      "id":"habit:150mg buoropion",
      "key":"habit",
      "value":null,
      "doc":{
        "meta":{
          "id":"habit:150mg buoropion",
          "rev":"1-00000700e0f3239a0000000000000000",
          "expiration":0,
          "flags":0
        },
        "json":{
          "type":"habit",
          "name":"150mg Buoropion",
          "color":"#D4A475"
        }
      }
    },
    ⋮
```

Is there way to use Sync Gateway to get a compatible view? Currently, I am working around it currently by returning the document as the value from the `map`.

Answer (score 0):

In your server view you should emit the data you need as the second parameter and do a query on the first parameter(s)

```
function (doc, meta) { 
    emit(meta.id, [ "name": doc.name,"color": doc.color ] );
}

view paramerters;
startkey = 'habit:150mg buoropion'
endkey = 'habit:150mg buoropion' + '\uefff'
```